# Get a element from a collection depending on type of element

Tags: java, algorithm, collections

I have an unsorted collection of at most 3 elements of same object. These elements have a property type which can be either A, B, or C.

I want to get 1 element from that collection based on the condition where type A has precedence over B, which has precedence over C.

Eg.

- {B, A, C} -> A
- {B, C} -> B
- {B} -> B
- {B, A} -> A
- {A, B} -> A

What would be the fastest or the most efficient way to do this. I have to perform this operation on thousands of collection.

I am using java, so I can use any type of collection.

Comment: Do you know `A`, `B` and `C` beforehand? I.e. do you have some instance of `A`, `B` and `C` you can work with?

Comment: Yes I know A, B, C beforehand. In fact I create the collection using streams `groupingBy`

Comment: Then just query the presence of `A`, `B` and `C` thorugh [`Collection#contains(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains(java.lang.Object)).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I should have been more clear with my question. Elements are not direct instances of A, B, C. They are stored in variables of elements.

Comment: I have tried direct brute force way. i.e. iterate over list if element has type A then return element, else iterate again for B.

Comment: @PragatiSureka ok, so what was the problem with your brute force approach? Please add more details to the question: the code of your brute force, how did you understand it's too slow for your problem (measurement techniques), what are your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of iterating through the list 3 times, you can do it in one iteration. Here's some pseudocode:

```
Element best = list.get(0);
for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Element cur = list.get(i);
    if (cur.isA() || (cur.isB() && best.isC())) {
        best = cur;
    }
}
// best will have property A if possible, then property B if possible, then C.
```

More precisely, this finds the last element with property A if one exists, else the first element with property B if one exists, else the first element. You can tweak the if statement logic to make those rules more consistent if your use-case requires that.